# Comparing the Dates and Sending an Email

Tags: excel, vba

I want to send an automatic mail if two conditions are met

1. The user input date in **Cell (17,2)** is  > than today's date in
   **Cell(22,2)**'
2. When the value in `Cell (B3) = "Operation_Support"`

When the above two conditions are met then I want an automatic mail to shoot up.

Can this be done?

The code is given below..

```
Sub datesexcelvba()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim mydate1 As Date
    Dim mydate2 As Long
    Dim datetoday1 As Date
    Dim datetoday2 As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim StrBody As String
    StrBody = "This is line " & "<br>" & _
    "This is line " & "<br>" & _
    "This is line " & "<br><br><br>"
    mydate1 = Cells(17, 2).Value
    mydate2 = mydate1
    datetoday1 = Cells(22, 2).Value
    datetoday2 = datetoday1
    If mydate2 > datetoday2 & Range("B3").Value = "Operation_Support" Then
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With mymail
            .To = "x"
            '& ";" & "x"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Test Mail"
            .HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng)
            .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
            ' You can add other files by uncommenting the following line.
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Display
        End With
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    ' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
    ' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook
    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
        SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
        Filename:=TempFile, _
        Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
        Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
        HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
    "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Use And not & to combine your conditions.

Comment: @TimWilliams Done.. gives an error Type Mismatch 13

Comment: @Mehul Rastogi: I tested the Code with the "And" and i had no Problems. What Version of Excel do you use?

Comment: @Moosli.. Thank you for your response.. I am using 2013.

Comment: @Moosli Did it generate an automated mail? is my code working fine? Also it gives an error Type Mismatch 13.. why this error? if you could help?

Comment: @MehulRastogi I didn't test the whole Code only the If mydate2 > datetoday2 And Range("B3").Value = "Operation_Support" Then Statement.

Comment: @Moosli Thank you so much.. will try n update the correct ans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tested your code and encountered some minor issues. Assuming your Function

```
RangetoHTML()
```

works fine, you need to change the following to lines

```
 If mydate2 > datetoday2 & Range("B3").Value = "Operation_Support" Then
 ...
 With mymail
 ...
```

The changes are the following: Replace the '&' with 'And' and 'mymail' with the Object you set above (in your case it is OutMail).

So your Sub would be:

```
Sub datesexcelvba()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim mydate1 As Date
Dim mydate2 As Long
Dim datetoday1 As Date
Dim datetoday2 As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim StrBody As String
StrBody = "This is line " & "<br>" & _
"This is line " & "<br>" & _
"This is line " & "<br><br><br>"
mydate1 = Cells(17, 2).Value
mydate2 = mydate1
datetoday1 = Cells(22, 2).Value
datetoday2 = datetoday1
If mydate2 > datetoday2 And Range("B3").Value = "Operation_Support" Then
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .To = "test@testing.com"
        '& ";" & "x"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Test Mail"
        .HTMLBody = StrBody
        '.Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        ' You can add other files by uncommenting the following line.
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Display
    End With
End If
On Error GoTo 0
With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```